# Gnucash: how to convert a huge XML data file into sqlite?

Tags: gnucash

I'm using Gnucash 2.4.13 and I have a big old XML data file (5 years of recording). I'd like to convert it to Sqlite file. Reason: I want to try some third-party apps that can make nice reports out of a Sqlite file. Examples: [Gnucash Reports Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syrkus.finances), [gnucash-django](https://github.com/nylen/gnucash-django), [django-openbudget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-openbudget/0.1.0).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, [gnucash can do this conversion](https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2009-December/032613.html). Open your XML datafile and then File->Save As and choose to save as an Sqlite file. This is also listed in the GnuCash instruction manual in [Chapter 2, The Basics](http://code.gnucash.org/docs/C/gnucash-guide/basics-files1.html).

Comment: Thank you, though I have only XML as a possible file format in a dropdown list. I tried to create a new file - the same thing, only XML option. I have Sqlite installed on my Ubuntu 13.10 machine. My Gnucash version is 2.4.13. Don't you know what can I do to enable other options?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. :( I can't suggest how to enable that. You may want to ask the gnucash people, if nobody else has an idea.

Comment: I figured it out. I installed the optional packages that come with Gnucash, enabling other database backends (postgres, mysql, sqlite), and the options appeared in the dropdown list. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks for following up! Hopefully, anyone else in your same situation will now be able to figure out the solution!