# Gnucash: how to breakdown assets by various accounts?

Tags: accounting, gnucash

Suppose I have the following accounts in Gnucash:

```
Assets
    Bank A
        Risky account, $1000
        Non-risky account, $2000
    Bank B
        Risky account, $5000
        Non-risky account, $7000
```

I can easily display a report with breakdown of assets by banks:

```
Bank B: $12000 (80%)
Bank A: $3000 (20%)
```

But how can I make a report like this:

```
Risky accounts: $6000 (40%)
Non-risky accounts: $9000 (60%)
```

?

In other words, I'd like to see what percent of assets are in one group of accounts, and what percent are in another group.

Of course, I can change the tree of accounts, but what I need is to breakdown the assets by various such 'trees'. It's like a faceted search, aggregating by various criteria.

Comment: This really isn't a personal finance question so much as a technical support question. Moving to a site where you might have better luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to create "groups" of accounts in Gnucash.

However, it is possible (with some work) to create a [custom report](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Custom_Reports) which might be able to do something like this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems quite hard to create a custom report. I wish somebody had a code of a custom report for the task I need. I think I'll first try other reporting tools from here: http://superuser.com/questions/739389/gnucash-how-to-convert-a-huge-xml-data-file-into-sqlite/739390?noredirect=1